# Store image directly to mysql (with php POST)

Tags: php

I am sending from PHP form image to server like

```
<input type="file" name="photo_1" />
```

On server I am doing this:

```
extract($_POST);
insertNewImage($photo_1); //insert into mysql , type is BLOB
```

But in database it is stored as `FILE NAME.jpg` and *not as binary*, so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide us with the code that you are using?

Comment: Why do you need to store file in database?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing

Answer (score 2):

> what I am doing wrong?

That is quite obvious: you're trying to store your images in the database instead of storing them in a filesystem.

Comment: Well I WANT then directly in database, so can server accept binary and store into database? Or I need to store in TMP location on server and then from there copy into database? Point is that I want directly stored in database.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't want to store files into your database.**

For this, you'd better store your image on your server, and for example put its name in your database. Then, with PHP code, you'll be able to retrieve your image by requesting the right name.

Comment: Ok maybe this is OK solution I supose, so please then help me, my files are photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, photo_x (total 10) in php form, how to "accept" and store on server side and to store their names into database?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that you should only save the name of the pic in the database:

If you want to do something with a uploaded file in PHP:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Uploaded files are stored in a different PHP variable. They are automatically generated as a temp file, if you check the information showed by the print_r you'll notice there's a field named `tmp_name`, you just have to copy `$_FILES['id_of_the_form_input']['tmp_name']` to the path you want to save the file in your system.